# Cocos2d CCMenuItemSprite in stacked menus not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to simulate a modal view in cocos2d by displaying a few sprites over my scene and showing a menuitemsprite as a continue button.  In the code below, i show my game over modal and have the menu set up with a CCMenuItemSprite; which does not respond to touches, and a CCMenuItemImage; which does work.

```
    -(void) gameOver {

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.menu.isTouchEnabled = NO;
    CCLayer *modalLayer = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
    [self addChild:modalLayer z:20];

    CCSprite *spriteGameOver = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"game_over.png"];
    spriteGameOver.position = ccp( size.width/2,size.height/2);

    CCLabelTTF *lblGameOver = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Over!\nScore %d/%d",numCorrect,questionIdx] dimensions:CGSizeMake(380, 300) alignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Trebuchet MS" fontSize:50.0f];
    // position the label on the center of the screen

    lblGameOver.position =  ccp(size.width/2-200, size.height/2-100);
    lblGameOver.color = ccc3(20, 20, 20);
    lblGameOver.opacity = 0;
    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [spriteGameOver addChild: lblGameOver];
    spriteGameOver.opacity = 0;
    [modalLayer addChild:spriteGameOver];

    CCSprite *spriteGameOverBtn = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainButton.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,300,60)];
    spriteGameOverBtn.position = ccp( size.width/2,size.height/2-100);
    CCLabelTTF *lblGameOverBtn = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Continue" dimensions:CGSizeMake(300, 60) alignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Trebuchet MS" fontSize:40.0f];
    //lblGameOverBtn.position =  ccp(size.width/2-200, size.height/2-300);
    [lblGameOverBtn setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.0f,0.1f)];
    lblGameOverBtn.color = ccc3(20, 20, 20);
    lblGameOverBtn.opacity = 0;
    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [spriteGameOverBtn addChild: lblGameOverBtn];
    spriteGameOverBtn.opacity = 0;

    CCMenuItemImage *itemH = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"backArrow.png" selectedImage:@"backArrowS.png" target:self selector:@selector(goToMain:)];
    itemH.position = ccp( size.width/2,size.height/2-100);

    CCMenuItemSprite *mGameOverBtn = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:spriteGameOverBtn selectedSprite:nil disabledSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(goToMain:)];

    CCMenu *menuGO = [CCMenu menuWithItems: itemH,mGameOverBtn, nil];
    menuGO.position = ccp( 0, 0);

    [modalLayer addChild:menuGO z:21]; 




    [lblGameOverBtn runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: 1.75f],nil]];

    [spriteGameOverBtn runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 3.75f],nil]];


    [lblGameOver runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 3.75f],nil]];

    [spriteGameOver runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration: 1.75f],[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 3.75f],nil]];

    //[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: 2.75f],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToMain:)], nil]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with CCMenuItemSprite too. It looks like the CCMenuItemSprite-class is a bit buggy. In my case it doesn't respond to touches. But I found out it has something to do with multi-layered Sprites inside the CCMenuItemSprite. So when I use a single-layered Sprite it works, but when I use a Sprite which contains multiple embedded sprites it doesn't.

My 'not-ready-yet' solution right now is setting the contentSize to the appropriate size of the CCMenuItemSprite right after it has been initialized:

```
        CCMenuItemSprite * menuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:multiLayeredSprite selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(clickHandler:)];
    [s setContentSize:backgroundSprite.contentSize];
    CCMenu * menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:
            menuItem,
            nil];
```

It's receiving touch-events now. The only problem I now have is the positioning of the Rectangle... it's still in the upper-right corner. I'll try to found out how to fix this now.
Hopefully this is clarifying a bit of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you have registered your scene with the touch dispatcher and your selectors actually do something?

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO]
```

Comment: The scene responds to touches and is used to get to the Game Over point.  In fact, when I displayed the Game over sprite on top of the menu, the menu would still respond.  So to cure that, I disabled the underlying menu.  So now the menu I want to work, is top Z order and is enabled.  My fall back will be to make the CCMenuItemImage a transparent image and be done with it.